# Two threads operate a std::deque, does below code have race condition?

Tags: c++, race-condition, deque

I have a small test to test if std::deque in my code have race condition/undefined behavior

```
num = 10000;
m = 0;
n = 0;
void push()
{
    while(num--) {
        {
            q.push_back(m);
        }
        printf("push succ: %d\n", m);
        //cout << "push succ: " << m << endl;
        m++;
        
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(4000));
    }
    cout << "m: " << m << endl;
}

void pop()
{
    while(true) {
        if (!q.empty()) {
            //cout << "q.size() " << q.size() << endl;
            printf("front: %d\n", q.front());
            {
                n++;
                q.pop_front();
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(4));
        }

        cout << "n: " << n << endl;
        if (stop && q.empty()) 
            break;        
    }
}
```

one thread push element, and the other pops element. `n` and `m` will record the operation times, I expect every element will be pushed once and be poped once. I run it on my MacOS, it sometimes will have duplicate element or missed element. I also run it on linux, but it's hard to reproduce.... I thought it's no problem if I check `empty()` before `pop_front` at first. But it seems not like this. I check the STL code, but not go through very deeply, still have no idea about the reason.[image]

Comment: Yes, that's a data race and therefore undefined behavior. `std::deque` is not thread-safe and not meant to be modified when multiple threads are involved without external synchronization. This applies to all standard library containers. You don't need to look at the implementation. It is specified in the ISO standard and you are not supposed to rely on a specific implementation of it. See e.g. cppreference.com for a reference.

Comment: Posting code with no synchronization being done between threads is automatically not thread safe.  The second thing is that multithreaded programming is more than knowing how to start threads.  It is a difficult topic that requires a lot of time, a lot of reading *good* C++ books concerning MT programming, etc.  It cannot be learned by trial and error.  Using `std::sleep_for` does not "slow things down" to do a fake synchronization of the code -- MT synchronization doesn't work this way.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: any attempt at synchronizing code using sleep's is broken.